# If the Dodo bird had a tradition of being kosher & was resurrected, would it be OK to eat again?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, halacha-theory, mesorah-tradition, non-kosher-species, birds

Came across an article titled ["Could scientists resurrect the dodo bird?"](https://animals.howstuffworks.com/extinct-animals/dodo.htm) and it made me wonder: suppose there was a *mesorah* that the Dodo bird was kosher before it went extinct in 1681.

If we in 2019/2020 were able to bring back this Dodo bird, would it again fall under its previous *mesorah* and be permissible for us to eat again?

Couple of larger questions that could contribute to the answer:

- Would written/ documented *mesorah* serve as enough proof **OR** do we literally need people passing it down from generation to generation
- Once the *mesorah* for a bird is gone it's gone forever **OR** it could potentially be "reawakened"?

Comment: The Torah prohibits certain birds with certain negative qualities. The rest are fair game ([pun](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_(hunting))?) shach ([82:6](https://www.sefaria.org/Siftei_Kohen_on_Shulchan_Arukh,_Yoreh_De'ah.82.6.1)) seems to say once it’s checked as part of the mesora, it need not be checked again, basically

Comment: I was told that in the town of Halberstadt, they used to shecht a pigeon every year in order to keep the mesorah. Further, I asked whether I could eat quails' eggs and was told not because we do not have a kabboloh of shechting quails. All stories - no sources.

Comment: Does the Mesorah discontinue just because the species goes extinct?

Comment: @DonielF yep was curious about that as well

Comment: I suspect, the WHOLE POINT of the tradition is that it does not break, that there aren't hundreds of years without practicing it. Once it's resurrected, nobody holds the tradition, nobody knows what it is.

Comment: I doubt there was ever a tradition, since it only lived on an island in the middle of the Indian Ocean.  There might be better examples of Middle Eastern/West Asian/European/North African birds, but I have no idea what they are.

Comment: Even if there was a mesorah, the method may have its own problems. I believe that most plans to revive extinct species involve placing the DNA of the extinct animal into an embryo, and implanting it into a female to get pregnant. I have no idea of what the halachic status of the engineered animal might be.

Comment: Hi, if it has all the signs of a kosher bird, then it would be permitted.The same question arose with turkeys.